# Windows variable in Sublime Text Build

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there any way to use Windows variable in Sublime text build. I have ih s build system:

Is there any way to use Windows variable in Sublime text build. I have ih s build system:

```
 {
    "name": "Python 11",
    "cmd": ["C:/Users/user01/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    },
```

I would kike to change user01 to be %USERNAME% as Windows variable so I don't have to change build system every time I switch computers. I have tried with `%username%` and `%username` but Sublime is not reading it's value.

I would kike to change user01 to be %USERNAME% as Windows variable so I don't have to change build system every time I switch computers. I have tried with `%username%` and `%username` but Sublime is not reading it's value.